# Google Cloud PubSub - How to send multiple arguments to the Cloud Function

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been using Google Cloud PubSub to trigger Google Cloud Functions. Until this point I have been using a single argument "uuid", now I need to send also development/production flag.

Here below is the publisher in Google App Engine/Django:

```
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_name = 'projects/project/topics/cloudfunction_topic'
    message_to_publish = video.uuid
    publisher.publish(topic_name, data=message_to_publish.encode('utf-8'), spam='')
```

Here below is the subscriber section in GCF:

```
    if os.getenv('GCF', None):
        uuid = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
```

How should I change this so there can be multiple arguments (video.uuid, production/development) in the message ?

Comment: Try serializing a dictionary of data as JSON.  That can be the payload of your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way (IMO) is to create a json structure, and serialize it into a utf-8 string on the sending side, and de-serialize it back into a json structure in the GCF.

Comment: You can also image putting the argument as attribute in the PubSub message. All depends the usage of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Pub/Sub message is base64 encoded, so you can write json and send it from Pub/Sub to the Cloud Function, OR you can pass Attributes from Pub/Bub and that is both json and plain text.

For example, if you run Pub/Sub manually like this:

[image]

You can add Attributes:

[image]

The word "test" is base64 but a console.dir(event) like this for example...

```
    exports.getData = (event, context) => {...
      console.dir(event);
```

...will show this in Cloud Logging:

[image]

It is then fairly easy to parse and use the Pub/Sub attributes in your Cloud Function.  Obviously, this is Node, but it would be similar in Python.